# When returning an instance of class Foo using self.__class__(), why does PyCharm think the type should be Optional[Type[Foo]]?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, python-typing

I have a class Foo that has a method that returns another Foo instance.

```
from __future__ import annotations

class Foo:
    def get_other_foo(self) -> Foo:
        return self.__class__()
```

(The `__future__` import is to make the `Foo` annotation on the method work in Python 3.7.)

This works, and MyPy doesn't flag any errors in the file. However, PyCharm highlights the return value in yellow, and when I hover over it I get the warning "Expected type 'Foo', got 'Optional[Type[Foo]]' instead".

I considered hard-coding Foo inside the method, like this:

```
from __future__ import annotations

class Foo:
    def get_other_foo(self) -> Foo:
        return Foo()
```

This also works, and silences the PyCharm warning. However, in a subclass this would return an instance of Foo instead of an instance of the subclass, so I am reluctant to do this.

Why does PyCharm think the return type should be `Optional[Type[Foo]]` in my first example? And is there a way to fix the PyCharm warning while keeping the ability of `get_other_foo()` to return a subclass instance when called from a subclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a known issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-37935, please vote!